# Subfield fixed by subgroup of Galois group if and only if subfield is fixed by generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

**Question**:

Let $G \leq \text{Gal}(K/F)$ be a subgroup of the Galois group of the extension $K/F$ and suppose $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$ are generators for $G$.  Show that the subfield $E/F$ is fixed by $G$ if and only if it is fixed by the generators $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$.

**My attempt**:

First suppose that the subfield $E/F$ is fixed by $G$.  This means that for any automorphism $\tau \in G$ one has $\tau(x) = x$ for all $x \in E$.  Since $G$ is generated by $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$ we certainly have that each of the automorphisms $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$ are elements in $G$ and therefore $\sigma_i(x) = x$ for all $x \in E$ and for each of $i = 1, 2, ..., k$.  In other words, the subfield $E$ is fixed by the generators $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$.

For the converse suppose hat the subfield $E$ is fixed by the generators $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$.  Now let $\tau \in G$ be an arbitrary automorphism.  Since $G$ is generated by the set $X = \sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$ we have that

$$
\tau = \tau_1^{\epsilon_1} \circ \tau_2^{\epsilon_2} \circ ... \circ \tau_r^{\epsilon_r}
$$

where $r \in \mathbb{N}, \tau_1, ..., \tau_r \in X$ and $\epsilon_1, ..., \epsilon_r \in \{-1, 1\}$.  Now, let $x \in E$ be any arbitrary element.  We have

$$
\tau(x) = \big(\tau_1^{\epsilon_1} \circ \tau_2^{\epsilon_2} \circ ... \circ \tau_r^{\epsilon_r}\big)(x).
$$

First, consider $\tau_r^{\epsilon_r}(x)$.  If $\epsilon_r = 1$ then $\tau_r^{\epsilon_r}(x) = \tau_r(x) = x$ since we are now assuming that the subfield $E$ is fixed by all of the generators, and $\tau_r$ is an automorphism which is precisely one of these generators $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_k$.  If instead $\epsilon_r = -1$, then we still have $\tau_r^{-1}(x) = x$ since $\tau_r$ is an automorphism (hence a bijection), and we know that $\tau_r(x) = x$.  Thus the above equality reduces to

$$
\tau(x) = \big(\tau_1^{\epsilon_1} \circ \tau_2^{\epsilon_2} \circ ... \circ \tau_{r-1}^{\epsilon_{r-1}}\big)(x),
$$

and after repetition of the same argument we eventually arrive at $\tau(x) = x$.  Since $\tau \in G$ was an arbitrary automorphism it follows that every automorphism from the subgroup $G$ fixes the subfield $E$.

Comment: Yup this works. Very meticulous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Here is also a shorter proof. Let:

$H=\{\sigma\in G: \sigma(x)=x \ \ \text{for all} \ \ x\in E\}$

It's very easy to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Since by assumption it contains a generating set of $G$, we must have $H=G$.